# How do you take a video of a program running on a headless machine

Tags: ubuntu, remote, video

I would like to take a video of what would run on the X Server on a remote machine and store that on my local machine. I thought of forwarding the X Session and using a screen capture tool, but ideally, I'd like to do this completely from the terminal and output a video.

Comment: For people who might look at this in the future http://afterdesign.net/2016/02/07/recording-headless-selenium-tests-to-mp4.html is a great reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you're looking for a combination of two things:

- [Xvfb,](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xvfb) a *virtual framebuffer X11 server*. It behaves just like an ordinary X server, but it needs no real display or even a GPU. It only needs a chunk of memory it can use as a framebuffer.
- a version of [ffmpeg with the x11grab support compiled in.](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop)